# Filling and extruding a curve

Tags: extrude, fcurves

[image]

How can I extrude a curve without converting it to a mesh? I want to do this so I can animate the spline while it's extruded.

Comment: Just extrude is possible: both is not possible (with just curves), but with geometry nodes, animation nodes and sverchok

Comment: @Chris how can you extrude it?

Comment: curve -> object data properties -> geometry -> extrude

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your curve is 2D, (and declared 2D in its Data tab > Shape panel) it can be  filled and extruded natively, in its own Shape and Geometry settings.. here, animated with Hooks:

[image]